# Meaning of “make labor of”

Tags: meaning, phrases

When someone says *not to make labor of it* what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven’t heard it, but it sounds as if it means ‘not to make excessive work out of something’. The British English equivalent might be *not to make a meal of it*. To someone who was doing just that, we might say *You’re making rather heavy weather of it*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was part of a dialog in Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: @eneepo: Then I should perhaps have recognized it! I don't think that exact expression would be heard today.

Comment: Google indicates that this is a line from a screenplay (of *A Scandal in Bohemia*) rather than a book; and it was "not to make a labour of it". Although that citation can be gleaned from the search results, I can't get at the source.

Comment: It was told by Mr. Hilton Cubitt to Sherlock Holmes (Jeremy Brett) in a dramatized version of "The dancing men".